# Flex TabbedViewNavigator Views Listen to List for Change Event

Tags: actionscript-3, list, apache-flex, events, tabbedviewnavigator

I have a view with a List on the left side, and a TabbedViewNavigator on the right.   How do I dispatch a list change event into the Views of the tabNavigator?   OR how do I listen from the views?

The main view holding the list and tabNavigator can hold list like this:

```
draftList.addEventListener(CustomEvent.EVENT_ITEM_SELECTED, draftListItemSelection);
```

Comment: I set bubbles to true on the event, then I was able to add the event listener to the stage from my tabbedNavigator views.

Comment: You found the solution?